# Andengine-How to create overlap and collide for Sprite in android game?

Tags: android, sprite, andengine

I am new to **Android game development** and I'm using **AndEngine GLES 2** Java. In this coding I have created 2 sprite which is **small_box** and **big_box** respectively.When I drag **small_box** to **big_box** or vice versa, it repels each other.This works fine, but my problem is that 1st **small_box** and 1st **big box** repel each other, but 2nd **small_box** and **big_box** doesn't repels.How can it be solved?. I want  all **small_box** repels from all **big_box**, and when I drag **small_box** to another **small_box** it should overlap and even in **big_box** to another **big_box** also........Plz anybody can help this by modifying this code or by using examples.......

```
public class SampleActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
    protected static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
    protected static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;
    private ITextureRegion Box1, Box2;;
    private Stack Stack1, Stack2;
    private Sprite small_box,big_box;
    //private final Sprite small_box = new Sprite[1];

    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED,
                new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
    }

    public void onCreateResources() {
        try {
            ITexture small_box = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(),
                    new IInputStreamOpener() {
                        public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                            return getAssets().open("gfx/small_box.png");
                        }
                    });
            ITexture big_box = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(),
                    new IInputStreamOpener() {
                        public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                            return getAssets().open("gfx/big_box.png");
                        }
                    });
            small_box.load();
            big_box.load();
            this.Box1 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(small_box);
            this.Box2 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(big_box);
            this.Stack1 = new Stack();
            this.Stack2 = new Stack();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Scene onCreateScene() {
        final Scene scene = new Scene();
        scene.setBackground(new Background(1, 1, 1));
        for( int i=0;i<2;i++){
            small_box = new Sprite(i*300, 100, Box1, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
                public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,  float pTouchAreaLocalX,  float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                    if (((Sprite) this.getmStack().peek()).getHeight() != this
                            .getHeight())
                        return false;
                    this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth()
                            / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                    if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        checkForCollisionsWithBoxes();
                    }
                    return true;
                  }
                private Stack getmStack() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return Stack2;
                }
              };
              big_box = new Sprite(i*300, 200, Box2, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
                    public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,  float pTouchAreaLocalX,  float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                        if (((Sprite) this.getmStack().peek()).getHeight() != this
                                .getHeight())
                            return false;
                        this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth()
                                / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
                        if (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP){
                            checkForCollisionsWithBoxes();
                        }
                        return true;
                      }
                    private Stack getmStack() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return Stack1;
                    }
                  };
                  scene.attachChild(small_box);
                  scene.attachChild(big_box);
                  this.Stack1.add(big_box);
                  this.Stack2.add(small_box);
                scene.registerTouchArea(small_box);
                scene.registerTouchArea(big_box);
                scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
        }
        return scene;
    }

    private void checkForCollisionsWithBoxes() {
        if ((big_box.collidesWith(small_box) && (Stack1.size() == 0 || small_box.getHeight() < ((Sprite) Stack1.peek()).getHeight()))) {
            small_box.setPosition(100+big_box.getWidth()/2, 50+ big_box.getHeight());
            big_box.setPosition(300+small_box.getWidth()/2, 250+small_box.getHeight()/2);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are only checking for the new boxes created , that's why

I suggest you use box2D for this, there is an example already for collisions in box2D and for filtered collisions if you need for example the small boxes to only collide with small boxes and not with big boxes

this is the link for filtering collisions
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/PhysicsCollisionFilteringExample.java

Comment: thank you for your response...i tried this link but i didnt get it...i used array for both sprite but it shows lengthy , i want to make it short....could u help me...

Comment: i used array for both sprite...i used 4 small box and 4 big box by using arrays...i did this coding but its lengthy so i want it scalable could any1 help me...if any1 ready to help me then i will share source code for this

Comment: don't use an array , use arraylist , that way you can add/remove them easier

Comment: Sorry, but it sounds like overkill to include the "massive" box2d for simple collision detection, a little bit of match would work fine. Of course, if there is further physics-related calculations, then perhaps it would be prudent to advise it.